# Is there any method to export Kibana dashboards to Grafana as it is?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, reporting, grafana

We are going through a product change and would like to export our dashboards from kibana to grafana. The data source used is ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't, you will need to recreate your Kibana dashboards in Grafana, the tools use different methods to create dashboards and are not compatible with each other.